# SQL query in Oracle to find number within ranges-field that represented in varchar column

Tags: sql, oracle, range

I have `Colors` table in Oracle, with data like:

```
ID    Color    Ranges (nvarchar2!)
--    -----    -------------------------
1     Blue     1-9,23.5-25.1,27.11,99.14
2     Red      4
3     Green    4.44-5.3
4     Black    18-22,101
```

As you can guess, the `Ranges` column represents some numbers and numbers-ranges.

I **can't** save the ranges in some other tables (like `RangesTable` with `ColorID`, `MinVal`, `MaxVal`), but I **can** normalize this `Ranges`-column in some ways (allways sorted, or, represting single-numbers as ranges ("`4-4`" instead of "`4`"), or such).

**The problem:** I'm searching for a way to query my Oracle according to this field, by asking it: *Which colors (or ids...) do I have that its ranges contains 5?* (the answer is Blue and Green), or *Which color overlaps "5-6" range?* (answer is, again, Blue [1-9] and Green [4.44-5.3]).

How can it be done? (I guess Regex won't help here...).

Is it sensable to write in-DB function that capable to split those ranges and search in it? Any other suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can get your ranges with this query:

```
SQL> select id
  2         , color
  3         , to_number(case when ranges like '%-%' then regexp_substr(ranges,'[^-]+',1,1) else ranges end) low_value
  4         , to_number(case when ranges like '%-%' then regexp_substr(ranges,'[^-]+',1,2) else ranges end) high_value
  5      from colors
  6     model
  7           return updated rows
  8           partition by (id,color)
  9           dimension by (0 i)
 10           measures (ranges,nvl(length(regexp_replace(ranges,'[^,]')),0) + nvl2(ranges,1,0) as number_of_parts)
 11           ( ranges[for i from 1 to number_of_parts[0] increment 1]
 12             = regexp_substr(ranges[0],'[^,]+',1,cv(i))
 13           )
 14  /

                  ID COLOR            LOW_VALUE           HIGH_VALUE
-------------------- ----- -------------------- --------------------
                   2 Red                      4                    4
                   1 Blue                     1                    9
                   1 Blue                  23.5                 25.1
                   1 Blue                 27.11                27.11
                   1 Blue                 99.14                99.14
                   4 Black                   18                   22
                   4 Black                  101                  101
                   3 Green                 4.44                  5.3

8 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a PL/SQL function like this:

```
function value_included (p_value in number, p_ranges in varchar2)
return number
is
    l_ranges_tab apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
    l_values_tab apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
    l_retval number := 0;
begin
    l_ranges_tab := apex_util.string_to_table (p_ranges, ',');
    for i in 1..l_ranges_tab.count loop
         l_values_tab := apex_util.string_to_table (l_ranges_tab(i), '-');
         if l_values_tab.count = 1 then
             if p_value = l_values_tab(1) then
                 l_retval := 1;
                 exit;
             end if;
         else
             if p_value between l_values_tab(1) and l_values_tab(2) then
                 l_retval := 1;
                 exit;
             end if;
         end if;
    end loop;
    return l_retval;
end;
```

This returns 1 if the value is included in the range(s), 0 if not and can be used like this:

```
select color from colors where value_included(5, ranges);
```

A similar function could be written to handle overlapping ranges:

```
function range_overlap (p_from in number, p_to in number, p_ranges in varchar2)
return number
is
    l_ranges_tab apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
    l_values_tab apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
    l_retval number := 0;
begin
    l_ranges_tab := apex_util.string_to_table (p_ranges, ',');
    for i in 1..l_ranges_tab.count loop
         l_values_tab := apex_util.string_to_table (l_ranges_tab(i), '-');
         if l_values_tab.count = 1 then
             if l_values_tab(1) between p_from and p_to then
                 l_retval := 1;
                 exit;
             end if;
         else
             if p_to >= l_values_tab(1) and p_from <= l_values_tab(2) then
                 l_retval := 1;
                 exit;
             end if;
         end if;
    end loop;
    return l_retval;
end;
```

Note: the apex_util.string_to_table function is available as standard in recent versions of Oracle; in earlier versions you may need to write your own string parser function like [this one](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/parsing-delimited-fields-in-character.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by using a SQL nested table and a pipelined function to provide a third option.

Firstly create the SQL type and related nested table:

```
create or replace type range_type as object (range_from number, range_to number);
create or replace type range_table as table of range_type;
```

Then create a pipelined function that can decode the range column. The function can probably easily be rewritten to take advantage of the apex_util.string_to_table function used above.

```
create or replace function range_to_nested_table(i_ranges in varchar2) 
  return range_table pipelined is

  thisRange varchar2(4000);
  loop_counter number := 1;

  output_row range_type;

begin

  loop
    thisRange := rtrim(regexp_substr(i_ranges, '[^,]*,?', 1, loop_counter), ',');

    exit when thisRange is null;
    loop_counter := loop_counter + 1;

    if thisRange like '%-%' then 
      output_row := range_type(to_number(regexp_substr(thisRange, '[^-]*', 1, 1)), 
                               to_number(regexp_substr(thisRange, '[^-]*(-|$)', 1, 2)));
    else
      output_row := range_type(to_number(thisRange), to_number(thisRange));
    end if;

    pipe row(output_row);

  end loop;

  RETURN;

end;
```

Then run the following query to retrieve the data:

```
with my_sample_data as (
  select 1 as id, 'Blue' as color, '1-9,23.5-25.1,27.11,99.14' as range from dual union all
  select 2 as id, 'Red' as color, '4' as range from dual union all
  select 3 as id, 'Green' as color, '4.44-5.3' as range from dual union all
  select 4 as id, 'Black' as color, '18-22,101' as range from dual
)
select id, color, range, b.*
from my_sample_data a, table(range_to_nested_table(a.range)) b
where 5 between b.range_from and b.range_to
```